# How to quicky connect to a sqlite database with OpenOffice.org Base?

Tags: openoffice

With Ubuntu:How to quicky connect to a sqlite database with OpenOffice.org Base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way currently is to use an ODBC driver to connect to SQLite.

This is explained in the OOo wiki:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_SQLite_With_OpenOffice.org